# Impex old pk has wrong format on import of custom component to content slot

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am trying to create an impex script in Hybris 6.4 in order to put my custom component into a ContentSlot via the ImpEx Import tool found in the Hybris Administration console.  When I run the impex, I get am, `old pk has wrong format: 'catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=apparel-ukContentCatalog])', type code is not an integer.[HY--1]` error.  I have used the BackOffice application to verify that my custom component is present. What do I need to do to assign my component to the ContentSlot without encountering the `old pk has wrong format: 'catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=apparel-ukContentCatalog])', type code is not an integer.[HY--1]` error?

**Here is my impex.**

```
<header line is blank>
$contentCatalog=apparel-ukContentCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Online])[default=$contentCatalog:Online]
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$catalogVersion;uid[unique=true];active;cmsComponents(uid, catalogVersion)
;;SearchResultsGridSlot;true;MyComponent:$catalogVersion
```

Note that I also tried this variation of the $catalogVersion macro:

```
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$contentCatalog]),version[default='Online'])[unique=true,default=$contentCatalog:Online]
```

**This is the stack trace for the impex attempt.**

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP27] (000002C5) [CronJobErrorHandler] line 5 at main script: Exception ocurred, will ignore: de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException: old pk has wrong format: 'catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=apparel-ukContentCatalog])', type code is not an integer.[HY--1]
de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException: old pk has wrong format: 'catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=apparel-ukContentCatalog])', type code is not an integer.
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processInsertUpdateLine(DefaultImportProcessor.java:483) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processItemData_Impl(DefaultImportProcessor.java:259) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processItemData(DefaultImportProcessor.java:158) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.processLine(ImpExImportReader.java:718) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.readLine(ImpExImportReader.java:518) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:251) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.importNextInternal(Importer.java:757) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.importNext(Importer.java:738) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.cronjob.ImpExImportJob.doImport(ImpExImportJob.java:290) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.cronjob.ImpExImportJob.performJob(ImpExImportJob.java:248) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.cronjob.ImpExImportJob.performCronJob(ImpExImportJob.java:115) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1390) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:814) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:732) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.perform(Job.java:644) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.impl.DefaultCronJobService.performCronJob(DefaultCronJobService.java:86) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.impl.DefaultImportService.importData(DefaultImportService.java:437) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.impl.DefaultImportService.importDataUsingStandardImpex(DefaultImportService.java:360) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.impl.DefaultImportService.importData(DefaultImportService.java:104) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.hac.facade.impl.DefaultImpexFacade.importData(DefaultImpexFacade.java:60) [classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.hac.controller.console.ImpexController.handleImpexImportContent(ImpexController.java:189) [classes/:?]
```

For further investigation, I tried removing the unique attribute from the $catalogVersion macro definition in order to see if any clues could be found, but the error encountered here seems to bolster the necessity of the presence of the unique key attribute on the $catalogVersion macro.

**Impex without unique attribute for catalogVersion**

```
<header line is blank>
$contentCatalog=apparel-ukContentCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Online])[default=$contentCatalog:Online]
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$catalogVersion;uid[unique=true];active;cmsComponents(uid, catalogVersion)
;;SearchResultsGridSlot;true;MyComponent:$catalogVersion
```

**Stack trace for impex without unique attribute**

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP29] (000002C4) [CronJobErrorHandler] line 5 at main script: Exception ocurred, will ignore: de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.AmbiguousItemException: More than one item of type ContentSlot found for unique qualifiers {uid2=SearchResultsGridSlot}[HY-0]
de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.AmbiguousItemException: More than one item of type ContentSlot found for unique qualifiers {uid2=SearchResultsGridSlot}
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultExistingItemResolver.resolveByQuery(DefaultExistingItemResolver.java:204) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultExistingItemResolver.findExisting(DefaultExistingItemResolver.java:133) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processItemData_Impl(DefaultImportProcessor.java:213) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.DefaultImportProcessor.processItemData(DefaultImportProcessor.java:158) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.processLine(ImpExImportReader.java:718) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.imp.ImpExImportReader.readLine(ImpExImportReader.java:518) ~[impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.doImport(Importer.java:251) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.importNextInternal(Importer.java:757) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.Importer.importNext(Importer.java:738) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.cronjob.ImpExImportJob.doImport(ImpExImportJob.java:290) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.cronjob.ImpExImportJob.performJob(ImpExImportJob.java:248) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.cronjob.ImpExImportJob.performCronJob(ImpExImportJob.java:115) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1390) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:814) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:732) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.perform(Job.java:644) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.impl.DefaultCronJobService.performCronJob(DefaultCronJobService.java:86) [processingserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.impl.DefaultImportService.importData(DefaultImportService.java:437) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.impl.DefaultImportService.importDataUsingStandardImpex(DefaultImportService.java:360) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.impex.impl.DefaultImportService.importData(DefaultImportService.java:104) [impexserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.hac.facade.impl.DefaultImpexFacade.importData(DefaultImpexFacade.java:60) [classes/:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.hac.controller.console.ImpexController.handleImpexImportContent(ImpexController.java:189) [classes/:?]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your catalogverison line different than examples. You try below code.

```
$contentCatalog=apparel-ukContentCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$contentCatalog]),version[default=Online])[unique=true,default=$contentCatalog:Online]
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$catalogVersion;uid[unique=true];active;cmsComponents(uid, $catalogVersion)
;;SearchResultsGridSlot;true;MyComponent
```

Working impex for this slot in standard system.

```
$contentCatalog=apparel-ukContentCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$contentCatalog]),version[default=Online])[unique=true,default=$contentCatalog:Online]
INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;$catalogVersion;uid[unique=true];active;cmsComponents(uid, $catalogVersion)
;;SearchResultsGridSlot;true;SearchResultsGrid
```

Comment: That variation does not work either.  I had tried this style as well before posting, but I gave it another try and I still encountered the "old pk has wrong format" error.

Comment: Please note that I added more information about the error in my question which was buried in the stack trace.

Comment: Can you try giving catalog version in insert_update line?

Comment: I understand that it is trying to use text (catalogVersion(CatalogVersi...) as pk in log.

Comment: I tried inserting catalog version into the insert_update line and had the same error. This is the line I tried: `INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot;catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Online])[default=$contentCatalog:Online, unique=true];uid[unique=true];active;cmsComponents(uid, catalogVersion)
`

Comment: Did you try catalogVersion as $catalogVersion for cmsComponents?

Comment: I updated my impex and it is look like working. It is giving not found error in my system for component MyComponent.

Comment: I copied your impex and it worked for me.  To be honest, I am completely baffled as to why it worked as I think I tried a version like yours at some point.  I am glad it is working now, but I wish I knew what was the cause of my issue.

Comment: It is to late for finding fault code for me, may be you need good sleep before rechecking it :)

I think your cmsComponents function parameter catalogVersion not working as expected. Because of function in function. It is set $catalogVersion as text to cmsComponents function.

Comment: I think you are right about the issue being the cmsComponents function needing to work with the $catalogVersion macro rather than the function parameter named catalogVersion.  I think this was one thing I did not alter because I was unsure of the flexibility of multiple parameter items in the header and the specification of the corresponding items in the value line for this particular data element.